# How to clear drive names/labels from windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, volume-label

I renamed a drive to m500 and another to m600 and now every time I plug in *ANY* external drive, windows will label it to m500 or m600.
I've tried 4 different drives of varying sizes (130gb - 5tb), same behavior.

Sometimes it'll duplicate too, so D: m500 and E: m500.

Guessing where windows stores the label info got corrupted but not sure how to clear that out?

Comment: Is that just a default name for a drive with *no* name? Have you tried renaming one of the new drives to something different, and does that new name now show correctly when the drive is unplugged and plugged in again?

Comment: Just to be clear.  You named the label of the drive those values?  Have you tried removing the labels?  You do this by right clicking on the drive and selecting rename.  I would not be shocked if the label for a drive is associated with the drive letter.

Comment: the default name should be "Local Disk". I was starring at too many "Local Disk" hence wanting to rename them.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik just tried that, so far as I can tell, it's only affecting drives without a specific label. I reformatted and renamed a drive to 'dddd' on pc #2 and tried plugging into the affected pc and it persisted as 'ddd'. But doing the same to another drive without a label results in the m500 thing.

Comment: So it seems it's just that an unlabelled drive shows as the default (now *m500*). Just label all drives.

Comment: naming each and every drive/flashdrive I'm going to ever plug in for the lifetime of this os image is not exactly a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it's stored as a registry entry here:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons
```

[image: Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons]

I deleted both entries for D and E (leaving \DriveIcons empty) and rebooted.
That fixed it for me.